# How to query a string value separated by comma in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

the result 1 is from table1:

```
select types from table1 where id = 123456;
```

result:

```
934046, 934049
```

then, the result 1 as a parameter to table2:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from table2 where id in (
    select types from table1 where id = 123456
);
```

but, the result 1 is a String value,
so result:

```
NULL
```

infact I wanna get this:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from table2 where id in ('934046', '934049');
or
select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from table2 where id in (934046,934049);
```

but it may still like this:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from table2 where id in ('934046,934049');

1.
select REPLACE(types,',','\',\'') types from table1 where id=123456

1.1 
result:  934046',' 934049

1.2 
select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from table2 where ids in ( 
select REPLACE(types,',','\',\'') types from table1 where id=123456
); 

2.
select CONCAT('\'',REPLACE(types ,',','\',\''),'\'') from table1 where 
id=123456

2.1 
reuslt: '934046',' 934049' 

2.2 
select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from table2 where ids in ( 
select CONCAT('\'',REPLACE(types ,',','\',\''),'\'') from table1 where 
id=123456);
```

this string value could not be able to as a parameter, What should I do to get the ids in right way?

Comment: if `types` is varchar,then `select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from table2 where id in ('934046', '934049')` is the suitable one to use

Comment: I know the problem ,but  it can't work

Comment: what do you mean by  `but it can't work`?

Comment: select  GROUP_CONCAT(name)  
from table2 
where ids in (
select REPLACE(types,',','\',\'') types
from table1 
where id=12344
);                types ==> 934046',' 934049  or 
             CONCAT('\'',REPLACE(types ,',','\',\''),'\'') ==>'934046',' 934049' ,when it put into tables as a parameter , the query result always null

Comment: I'm sorry... but why selecting types from table1 return a string and not two rows with ids?

Comment: becaues 'types' is a field of table1，its value like '1234,1234,1234'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) from table2 t
where exists(
    select 1 from table1
    where id = 123456
    and LOCATE(concat(', ', t.id, ',') , concat(', ', types, ',') )>0
)
```

sql will like this:

```
    select GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) from table2 t
    where exists(
      select 1 from table1
      where id = 123456
      and LOCATE(concat(',', 1, ',') , concat(', ', '1,2,3', ',') )>0
    )
```

using function concat()  to let t.id and types have the same format,then use LOCATE() to find whether t.id exists in types

Comment: some one give the answer , but I don't know why he deleted it . anyway , thank you all

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select types from table1 where id = 123456"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $array[] = $row['types'];
}

$array = implode(",",$array);

$query2 = "select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from table2 where id in ($array)";
```

I have created code with a different query.